# Custom class initialisation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I'm trying to implement a custom class extending UIControl in swift and can't quite work out the  initialisation.

```
class UIRangeSlider: UIControl {
    var minimumValue: Float32
    var maximumValue: Float32

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, minimumValue: Float32, maximumValue: Float32) {
        self.minimumValue = minimumValue
        self.maximumValue = maximumValue
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of this class with:

```
var sliderFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 200, height: 5)
var slider = UIRangeSlider(frame: sliderFrame, minimumValue: 1, maximumValue: 10)
```

I get the error:

```
Property 'self.minimumValue' not initialised at super.init call
```

What is the correct way to write this custom initialiser?

Comment: All non-optional properties must be initialized at compile time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift always requires any new members of class to have some kind of default value before you can call designated `init`.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.minimumValue = 0.0 // some default value
    self.maximumValue = 0.0 // some default value

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to alter the coder function to take more parameters? Or is there any other way to only allow initialisation with a given minimum and maximum value?